# Python3 Multi-Lined String Print Next

Tags: python-3.x, string, printing, iterator

How can I print the line below each line starting with "string" using the next() function? I have only found answers for how to do it out of a .txt document but I would not want to use a text document in this situation. Here is what I have tried/have so far...

```
longString = """
    string1
    01

    string2
    02

    string3
    03
    """
lines = longString.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith(str(mylist[0])): # The mylist[0] is "string"
        print(line)

Output:
string1
string2
string3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
longString = """
string1
01

string2
02

string3
03
"""
lines = iter(longString.split('\n'))
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("string"):
        print(next(lines))

Output:
01
02
03
```

You need an actual iterator (not just an iterable sequence) to use `next()` - and the built-in `iter()` function does just this.

Note that I had to remove the leading spaces within your string - none of the lines actually started with "string" the way you had it.